# Is it possible to automatically deduce the type of the pointer to member overloaded function in ternary when called after?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member

So I had this scenario where I want to call either function of a class, where the function in question has the same prototype but it's also overloaded. Since I know of pointer to members my immediate reaction was something like this:

```
struct test
{
    int overloaded(char) {}
    int overloaded(int) {}
    int overloadedone(char) {}
    int overloadedone(int) {}
} test;

int main()
{
    (test.*(true ? (&test::overloaded) : (&test::overloadedone)))(1);
}
```

However it turned out the compiler (MSVC - 2019 Preview latest version with std C++ preview) can't deduce the type and I have to write:

```
(test.*(true ? static_cast<int (test::*)(int)>(&test::overloaded) : static_cast<int (test::*)(int)>(&test::overloadedone)))(1);
```

instead which made me return to the good old:

```
true ? test.overloaded(1) : test.overloadedone(1);
```

But I wonder if this is the defined behavior of requiring those cast. Even:

```
(test.*static_cast<int (test::*)(int)>(true ? (&test::overloaded) : (&test::overloadedone)))(1);
```

Doesn't work.

You have to write said cast on each of the two possibilities for the ternary as in the second example.

Comment: There ain't no such thing as a pointer to an overloaded set of member functions. The overload resolution must be performed, and an address of a particular overload taken. The standard defines several contexts in which this is possible: within a cast, or on the right-hand side of an initialization or assignment; the type of the cast or the type of the left-hand side guide the overload resolution. You are trying to take an address of an overloaded member function outside of those specific contexts.

Comment: The expression `(true ? (&test::overloaded) : (&test::overloadedone)))` doesn't work because there are two candidates for each of `overloaded` and `overloadedone` that each have distinct types.   The result is ambiguity.    That expression needs to be unambiguously evaluated before apply the `static_cast` to the result.

Comment: You can do something like this though: https://godbolt.org/z/bnrM44

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Unfortunately it's a library I'm using and have no control over.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't particularly elegant, but this approach can deduce an overload if you curry the member function pointer's arguments before passing the member function pointers themselves:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class... Args>
auto invoke_conditional_mem_fn(Args... args)
{
    return [=] <class R, class X> (X x, bool b, R(X::*t)(Args...), R(X::*f)(Args...)) -> R
    {
        return (x.*(b ? t : f))(args...);
    };
}

struct test
{
    int overloaded(char) { std::cout << "overloaded(char) "; return 1; }
    int overloaded(int) { std::cout << "overloaded(int) "; return 2; }
    int overloadedone(char) { std::cout << "overloadedone(char) "; return 3; }
    int overloadedone(int) { std::cout << "overloadedone(int) "; return 4; }
} test;

int main()
{
    std::cout
        << invoke_conditional_mem_fn('1')(test, true, &test::overloaded, &test::overloadedone)
        << std::endl
        << invoke_conditional_mem_fn(1)(test, false, &test::overloaded, &test::overloadedone)
        << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks to [@dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp) and [their example](https://godbolt.org/z/n3hG1G), we know that we can infer the return type and base of the member function pointers if we select which arguments to pass.

---

Alternatively, you could do something a little simpler like this, if it meets your needs. Just declare a lambda to work around the limitations of your ternary expression with an `if` and `else` statement since each branch of a ternary operator is required to be of the same type.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct test
{
    int overloaded(char) { std::cout << "overloaded(char) "; return 1; }
    int overloaded(int) { std::cout << "overloaded(int) "; return 2; }
    int overloadedone(char) { std::cout << "overloadedone(char) "; return 3; }
    int overloadedone(int) { std::cout << "overloadedone(int) "; return 4; }
} test;

auto conditional = [] (struct test& test, bool cond, auto... args)
{
    if (cond) return test.overloaded(args...);
    else return test.overloadedone(args...);
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << conditional(test, true, '1') << std::endl;
    std::cout << conditional(test, false, 1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe improve by deducing the return type via a two-step deduction? If you have the argument types, you can deduce the rest while selecting an overload: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/n3hG1G

Comment: Hmmm just from an aesthetical point of view, I'd separate the member functions from the other arguments: `invoke_conditional(test, true, '1')(&test::overloaded, &test::overloadedone)`.

Comment: @dyp I don't think that particularly matters, I'll let OP choose how they wish to separate their arguments since doing that is fairly trivial compared to the rest.

Comment: @dyp _is that even possible?_ ah, I don't know why I thought it was, evidently it's not, good point. I'll remove that comment.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts If you have two functions that differs only by return type, **the code does not compile.** C++ never use return type to select an overload exception for conversion operator but then you cannot have the same name anyway!

Comment: @Phil1970 the comment was removed, I realized my mistake when I got back just a few minutes ago.